Can I create a column in a list that displays the outcome of a logical test across multiple Yes/No questions?
I'm new to SharePoint and I have created a list to capture responses that I want to test and automatically calculate and display an outcome in a new column called ("Result") in the list.
There are 6 questions in the list that are all "Yes/No". In Excel I can accomplish the result I want using this formula;
*(noting I've replaced the cell ranges in Excel in this example with the word QUESTIONx, so QUESTION1:QUESTION4 means the countif result of QUESTION1,2,3 and 4)*
=IF(COUNTIF(QUESTION5:QUESTION6,"Yes")>0,"Tier 1",IF(COUNTIF(QUESTION1:QUESTION4,"Yes")>0,"Tier 2","Tier 3"))
How do I achieve the same in the SharePoint list please?

Assuming that you have column names like Question1,Question2,...,Question6 as choice type with ["Yes","No"] options.
You can create Result column as a calculated column in the list and use below formula in it:
=IF(
    OR([Question5]="Yes", [Question6]="Yes"),
    "Tier 1",
    IF(
        OR([Question1]="Yes", [Question2]="Yes", [Question3]="Yes", [Question4]="Yes"),
        "Tier 2",
        "Tier 3"
    )
)


You can create a calculated column with a formula like this:
=IF(OR([QUESTION5]=TRUE, [QUESTION6]=TRUE), "Tier 1", IF(OR([QUESTION1]=TRUE, [QUESTION2]=TRUE, [QUESTION3]=TRUE, [QUESTION4]=TRUE), "Tier 2", "Tier 3"))

This formula checks if either or is Yes (TRUE). If so, it returns "Tier 1". If not, it checks if any of , , , or is Yes (TRUE) and returns "Tier 2". If none of these conditions are met, it returns "Tier 3".
To create this calculated column in your SharePoint list:

Go to your list settings.Click on "Create column".
Choose "Calculated (calculation based on other columns)".
Enter the formula above in the formula box.
Set the data type returned from this formula to "Single line of
text" or "Choice" based on your needs.

